# Is there a way to swap layers or views in the middle of a CAKeyframeAnimation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, layer

I am running a keyFrame animation to move and flip a playing card view using CAKeyframeAnimation. is there any way to swap the cardFront and cardBack layers during the animation? or am i taking the wrong approach here...

Answer (score 0):

use a timer set to half the animation duration to execute cardBack.contents = cardFront.contents